# OAuth-Ruby gem returning 401 when trying to get access_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to implement OAuth as a sign-in option on my app. Most providers have been working really well, but Twitter has been giving me a ton of trouble.

I'm able to get a request token and be sent an `oauth_verifier`.  However, after that I'm unable to get an authorized response from Twitter using the [oauth-ruby](https://github.com/oauth-xx/oauth-ruby) gem.

*I cannot use Devise or Omniauth in my setup.*

Here is a minimalist and annotated version of my code:

```
# controllers/authorizations_controller.rb
# route: POST /auth/twitter
def create
    if params[:oauth_token].blank? # This gets hit as the first part of the process.  This entire block works as expected
      oauth = Oauth::Twitter.get_token
      session['oauth_token'] = oauth

      render json: { oauth_token: oauth.token } # The user authorizes and is redirected (to this same action)
    else # Once authorized, the oauth_token params is set and this gets executed
      Oauth::Twitter.new(params, session['oauth_token'])
    end
end
```

---

```
# models/oauth/twitter.rb
class Oauth::Twitter < Oauth::Base
  def self.get_token # This seems to work
    consumer.get_request_token(oauth_callback: 'http://localhost:3000') # This must be set to 'http://localhost:3000' per my frontend library
  end

  def initialize(params, request_token_hash)
    consumer = self.class.consumer

    request_token = OAuth::RequestToken.from_hash(consumer, request_token_hash) # This returns the expected RequestToken object
    request_token.get_access_token(oauth_verifier: params[:oauth_verifier]) # This is where the 401 is thrown.  params['oauth_verifier'] is confirmed to be set.
  end

  private

  def self.consumer
    OAuth::Consumer.new(
      Rails.application.secrets['TWITTER_KEY'],
      Rails.application.secrets['TWITTER_SECRET'], 
      :site => "https://api.twitter.com"
    )
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, I don't get any more information than a thrown `401 Authorization Required).  Between the [Twitter docs for sign-in via OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing) (more specifically, the [oauth/access_token](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/access_token) endpoint) and [a similar example](https://github.com/javidjamae/ruby-oauth-example/blob/master/oauth.rb) using the same OAuth gem, I can't see where my mistake lies.

Comment: Can you show the logs for the request?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh If I'm being honest, I'm not sure how.  The OAuth gem that handles the request seems to not log anything.

Comment: you can follow https://github.com/oauth-xx/oauth-ruby#demonstration-of-usage and post the output of that code tested in your console